# TFS 2018 Web Access download from large file on Windows 10 Clients no more possible

Tags: tfs, download, filesize, web-frontend

We have a TFS 2018 Update 3.2 where we store some Files in Code-Section (from about 8MB on and larger)

On our Windows 7 PC's it was never a Problem to do the download of these files in Web Access.

Now that we moved to Windows 10 almost every new PC is not able to download bigger Files - small Files are still no Problem. Actually just one Windows 10 PC still does the job - that's the only one which was upgraded from Windows 7. It depends on the Computer, not on the User.

Upload of Files bigger than 8MB ist still no Problem.

The Web Page ends up - after a long time - with Server Fault 0.

We already compared every internet option we found - the TFS in the Intranet Zone and Security Settings for Zones are on Microsoft Default.

Browser Edge and Internet Explorer V11 same effect. [10 minutes the Browser tries to download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcb5O.png) but in the End we get Status Code 0

Anybody with good ideas? Otherwise we would have to start our Windows 7 machines again :-(

Comment: Can you check out the large files with Team Explorer in Visual Studio?  Do you have any domain or local policy settings which block downloading the large files?

Answer (score 0):

I can download the large files (bigger than 8MB) successfully from TFS 2018 Update 3.2 using Windows 10 client.

So, please check the following things to narrow down the issue:

- Try to check out the large files with Team Explorer in Visual Studio
  using Windows 10 and check if that works.
- Check if you have set the domain or local policy settings which block
  downloading the large files.
- Press F12 in the browser and check if there are any error or warning
  messages in the console, you can troubleshoot accordingly based on
  the messages.
- Check the firewall settings and make sure no any settings blocked the
  downloading.
- Try to disable antivirus software, then try it again.

Please also try the things mentioned in this blog : [Can’t download files from the internet in Windows 10](https://windowsreport.com/cant-download-files-windows/). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It`s not the firewall but the network:
When I change the Workstation NIC to an NBase-T USB Adapter 5Gbit/s everything works.
Tried to change Switch of Worksations to 1Gbit hardware - no success
The machine that was ok all the time has a 10Gbit/s NIC.
Problem now: we have a mixed environment: Workstations with 1Gbit/s NIC an others with 10Gbit/s NIC
Connections are all on autosense.
I can`t change Speed on TFS NIC to only 1Gbit because:
Workstations -> 10Gbit/s NBase-T Switch -> Hypervisor 10Gbit/s NIC -> virtualSwitch used by several VM`s and has to be 10Gbit/s -> TFS (because of virtualSwitch no Speed setting available)
Is there a Possibility to get that working on Workstations 1Gbit/s AND Workstations 10Gbit/s AND workstations NBase-T 5Gbit/s ?